# Heroku FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, zip, joblib

I'm trying to deploy a Machine Learning model, which is inside a zip file due to its size. I'm trying to read the model using joblib, but I'm getting an error message.

This is the code portion:

```
    def unzip_model():
        with ZipFile("service/ProperatiBestModel14.zip", 'r') as zip:
            print('Extracting all the files now...')
            zip.extractall()
        mod = joblib.load("service/gbm.pkl")
        return mod
```

and this is the error message:

> 2020-12-10T03:33:40.574939+00:00 app[web.1]:     preprocessing =
> HousingService()
>
> 2020-12-10T03:33:40.574947+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/service/model_service.py", line 22, in **init**
>
> 2020-12-10T03:33:40.575054+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.lgbm =
> self.__unzip_model()
>
> 2020-12-10T03:33:40.575073+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/service/model_service.py", line 18, in __unzip_model
>
> 2020-12-10T03:33:40.575168+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod =
> joblib.load("service/gbm.pkl")
>
> 2020-12-10T03:33:40.575255+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py",
> line 577, in load
>
> 2020-12-10T03:33:40.575429+00:00 app[web.1]:     with open(filename,
> 'rb') as f:
>
> 2020-12-10T03:33:40.575463+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno
> 2] No such file or directory: 'service/gbm.pkl'
>
> 2020-12-10T03:33:40.706453+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1
>
> 2020-12-10T03:33:40.744274+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
> starting to crashed

I've already tried with different ways to assign the directory like os.getcwd() but nothing works.

Comment: is the zip-file part of the GIT repository you are pushing to Heroku?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the same repository. Also, Heroku and the code can find the zip file. The problem comes when I need to grab the file that was inside the zip file once I unzip everything with zip.extractall()

Comment: just came back to this. 

When is the unzip-code exactly called? 

It has to be on the same dyno it will be accessed, or while building the image. 

If you are using a worker-dyno, or one-off, or release process to unzip, these will be separate filesystems.